# Prevent error of missing handler in controller

Tags: ember.js

How can we normally prevent `Nothing handled the action` error in generic view implementation.
Currently I am reopening controller class and adding empty handler but again if I put it directly Ember throws deprecation message `Action handlers implemented directly on controllers are deprecated` if I add it in action object it is "not working" (probably overridden) and throws error as if it is not in base controller. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a somewhat hacky way to do it, you can add the method to the `_actions` object on the controller. That's where Ember internally keeps all of the actions for an object. Unfortunately, there's no other way to really handle an unused action from a view. [This issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/4920) suggested a feature that would allow you to, but it hasn't been implemented yet.

Personally, I don't use straight views at all, I only use components. Components allow you to subscribe to particular events (let them bubble up) and ignore the others completely.

Comment: Thanks, "hacky way" handles this.